# Convert string of parenthetical texts to HTML option tags

Tags: php, html, html-select, text-parsing

Please tell me if there is such a php code.

```
<select>
<?php
    $i = "(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)";
    $i2 = "(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)";
    $i = str_replace("(", "<option>", $i);
    $i = str_replace(")", "</option>", $i);
    $i2 = str_replace("(", "", $i2);
    $i2 = str_replace(")", "", $i2);
    $i = str_replace("<option>", "<option value='".$i2."'>", $i);
    echo $i;
?>
</select>
```

The code output is as follows:

```
<select>
    <option value="onetwothreefourfive">one</option>
    <option value="onetwothreefourfive">two</option>
    <option value="onetwothreefourfive">three</option>
    <option value="onetwothreefourfive">four</option>
    <option value="onetwothreefourfive">five</option>
</select>
```

How to make value look like this (value is correct):

```
<select>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
    <option value="five">five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can use loop

Comment: @YasinPatel Show on an example please.

Comment: That code outputs `a1`??? Where does that come from?

Comment: @kerbholz Refresh the page and read the question.

Comment: This question really doesn't make much sense... what's **exactly** are you trying to do? Where did that weird random PHP code come from in the first place? Why are you not just outputting what you want?

Comment: Ok, code edited. In HTML you can leave out the `value="xyz"` part in `option`s. If no `value` attribute is included, the value defaults to the text contained inside the element.

Comment: please clarify what you are asking in the question. your question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You'd be better of starting with an array. You can get there with `trim` and `explode` though. From an array it is easy with `foreach` to build this.

```
<?php
$word_numbers = explode(')(', trim('(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)', '()'));
?>
<select>
<?php    
foreach($word_numbers as $number) {
    echo '<option value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>' . PHP_EOL; 
}
?>
</select>
```

https://3v4l.org/JSCt1

...As an array...

```
$word_numbers = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
foreach($word_numbers as $number) {
    echo '<option value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>' . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are grappling with an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).

The hard truth is that there is 100% no reason to declare the `value` attribute of an option tag if it is identical to the option's text.

Replace the parentheses with option tags and your form will work flawlessly.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sG4SV))

```
$string = "(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)";
printf(
    "<select>%s\n</select>",
    str_replace(
        ['(', ')'],
        ["\n<option>", '</option>'],
        $string
    )
);
```

Output:

```
<select>
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
<option>three</option>
<option>four</option>
<option>five</option>
</select>
```

---

This also works to extract single words from the sample string. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XvkXK))

```
$string = "(one)(two)(three)(four)(five)";
printf(
    "<select>\n<option>%s</option>\n</select>",
    implode("</option>\n</option>", str_word_count($string, 2))
);
```